# Solve integral resembling a gaussian

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, probability-theory, analysis

I am trying to evaluate the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{2}xe^{\frac{-(s-2x)^2}{4\sigma^2}}dx$$

$$\lim_{t\to -\infty}\int_{t}^c\sqrt{2}xe^{\frac{-(s-2x)^2}{4\sigma^2}}dx + \lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{c}^t\sqrt{2}xe^{\frac{-(s-2x)^2}{4\sigma^2}}dx $$

We start by evaluating $\lim_{t\to -\infty}\int_{t}^c\sqrt{2}xe^{\frac{-(s-2x)^2}{4\sigma^2}}dx$. We perform a $u$-substitution. Let $u=s-2x$. Then $\frac{du}{-2}=dx$ and $\frac{u-s}{-2}=x$.

$$\int_{t}^c\sqrt{2}xe^{\frac{-(s-2x)^2}{4\sigma^2}}dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4e^{4\sigma^2}}\int_{s-2t}^{s-2c}(u-s)e^{-u^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4e^{4\sigma^2}}\left[\int_{s-2t}^{s-2c}ue^{-u^2}du-\int_{s-2t}^{s-2c}se^{-u^2}\right]$$

however this integral involves the error function. What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: The first integral is not convergent? You forgot a "-"?

Comment: @Youem Ah of course thank you. My question still stands

Comment: With $u=s-2x$, the integral with the factor of $u$ outside can be done without the error function while the other integral requires the famous "Gaussian integral trick" of squaring and changing to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an integral of this form can be re-written using algebraic manipulations by "adding zero" in the following way:
$$
\int xe^{-(cx-a)^2/2\sigma^2}\,dx = \int(x-a/c)e^{-(x-a/c)^2/2(\sigma/c)^2}\,dx + (a/c)\int e^{-(x-a/c)^2/2(\sigma/c)^2}\,dx.
$$
The first integral on the right-hand side is zero because the integrand is an odd function about $x = a/c$, and the second integral is the usual Gaussian integral, so the overall evaluation is $(a/c)\sqrt{2\pi (\sigma/c)^2}$.

Comment: This is a really good trick thank you!